# Why does adding a top border to a subview does not resize with auto layout/device rotation?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios8

(using Xcode 6 and iOS 8)

How can I create a top border in a sub UIView that sizes correctly when the view changes due to auto layout or device rotation?

I have code draws a line as the top border but it uses the size of what I have in Interface Builder. It does not size correctly after auto layout resizes the view nor after device rotation.

In the UIViewController, I tried `[self.view layoutSubviews]`, `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`, `[self.myCustomView layoutIfNeeded]`, and so on, in following method because when this method is called, the view has been resized by auto layout. But doesn't change the size of the line.

UIViewController:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];    
  [self.myCustomView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Hierarchy is:
UIViewController -> ViewController's View -> my custom UIView

Tried 2 different methods to draw the border which do draw the lines in my-custom-uiview. Neither one is recalled after the view is resized by auto layout or device rotation. This really shouldn't be that hard!

myCustomUIView:
First method:

```
// in initWithCoder, initWithFrame, awakeFromNib methods
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
border.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, 2.0f);
border.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;    
[self.contentView.layer addSublayer:border];
```

Second method:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  UIBezierPath *line = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
  [line moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
  [line addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, 0)];
  [line setLineWidth:2.0f];
  [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
  [line stroke];
}
```